# Accessing the variable of a class instead of the value

Tags: xcode

Let's say I have a player class that contains the variables **a, b, c** and **d**.

Depending on certain circumstances, either one of these variables will be passed to a function, e.g. `[self calculateSomethingWithVariable: player.c]`;

What I'm having trouble doing is trying to figure out how to do something like this:

```
- (void)calculateSomethingWithVariable:(Type *)Value {
      Value = something;
}
```

where `Value` should be **player.a** or **player.b** instead of the actual value of **a** or **b**, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - don't use upper case names for variables. It makes it hard to tell what's a variable and whats a type.

Secondly, you can change your code to something like this:

```
- (void)calculateSomethingWithVariable:(Type **)variableRef {
     *variableRef = something;
}
```

Basically you pass a pointer to a variables rather than a direct reference. So when calling this you do (presuming your alb, c and d are properties of a Player class:

```
Type *localC = player.c:
[self calculateSomethingWithVariable: &localC];
Player.c = localC;
```

This is the sort of approach taken in some of Apple's APIs where the variable to be set needs to be passed rather than it's value. In your case (presuming the code is basically as simple as your example) it would be much simpler to just return the new value:

```
- (Type *)calculateSomethingWithVariable:(Type *)oldValue {
     // Do something with old value.
     return somethingBasedOnOldValue;
}
Player.c = [self calculateSomethingWithVariable: player.c];
```